# Calculating the depth of a BST differently

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

How would you calculate the depth of a BST if you were to declare it without any parameters. I know you can do it like following with parameters:

```
public class BST {
    public int maxDepth(TreeNode root) {
        if(root==null) return 0;
       int left=maxDepth(root.left);
       int right=maxDepth(root.right);
       return Math.max(left,right)+1;
   }

}
```

But is it possible to do it without parameters like this:

```
public int maxDepth(){}
```

Provided that we can access the root and its left and right children of the BST from within the method?

Answer (score 0):

With little info from the question and many guesses :

```
    public int maxDepth() {
        return maxDepth(root);
    }
```

the rest of the code:

```
public class BST {
    public int maxDepth() {
        return maxDepth(root);
    }

    public int maxDepth(final TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null)
            return 0;
        final int left = maxDepth(root.left);
        final int right = maxDepth(root.right);
        return Math.max(left, right) + 1;
    }

    public TreeNode root;

    public static class TreeNode {
        public TreeNode left, right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but what I was really asking for was how to do what you did in your answer, but with only one maxdepth method with no parameters?

Answer (score 0):

you are asking to rewrite a recursive algorithm to an iterative form.

The general solution is a stack.

In this case, we use the stack to keep track of the current node. We traverse the tree by putting the currentNode to the `parent` stack. This makes `parent.peek()` the current node.

The second information that we need, if we traverse the tree layer by layer, is which node to visit next. For that, we use a second stack (it represents the inner state of your function). The second stack stores the next step (LEFT, RIGHT, DOWN).

It looks complicated, but we have to do some stuff by hand, which is hidden in the function stack of any programming language. Stack.pop corresponds to a function return. Stack.push prepares paramters for the next iteration.

We end up with the following program:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class BST {

    static class TreeNode {
        TreeNode right, left;
    }

    TreeNode root;

    static final int LEFT = 1;
    static final int RIGHT = 2;
    static final int UP = 3;

    public int maxDepth() {

        if (root == null)
            return 0;

        Stack<TreeNode> parent = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Integer> nextTurn = new Stack<>();

        int max = 0;

        parent.push(root); // parent.peek() is the currentNode.
                            // parent.size() is the current depth
        nextTurn.push(LEFT);
        while (!parent.isEmpty()) {
            switch (nextTurn.pop()) {
            case LEFT: // descend left (both subtrees left)
                nextTurn.push(RIGHT);
                if (parent.peek().left != null) {
                    parent.push(parent.peek().left);
                    nextTurn.push(LEFT);
                }
                break;
            case RIGHT: // descend right (left subtree done)
                nextTurn.push(UP);
                if (parent.peek().right != null) {
                    parent.push(parent.peek().right);
                    nextTurn.push(LEFT);
                }
                break;
            case UP: // go up (both subtrees done)
                if (parent.peek().left == null && parent.peek().right == null) {
                    // counting happens here.
                    // we are leaving a leaf node.
                    max = Math.max(max, parent.size());

                }
                parent.pop();
                break;
            }

        }
        return max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // small test:
        BST me = new BST();
        me.root = new TreeNode();

        me.root.left = new TreeNode();
        me.root.right = new TreeNode();

        me.root.left.left = new TreeNode();
        me.root.left.right = new TreeNode();
        me.root.left.left.right = new TreeNode();

        me.root.left.left.right.right = new TreeNode();

        System.out.println(me.maxDepth());

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a more simple way to do this?

Comment: if ia hava a guess, no. You somehow have to recreate the functionality of the function stack. You could use just one stack which contains state objects (holding parent and lastTurn in one struct). Maybe that would not confuse as much as two stacks. But the concept remains.